# iOS - display UICollectionViewCells on a single row

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I am trying to display all the cells on my UICollectionView on a single row with an hozizontal scroll.

For this, I am using the built in UICollectionView class but I created a subclass of UICollectionViewFlowLayout with the following code:

```
@implementation MemberCollectionViewFlowLayout

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
        self.minimumLineSpacing = 10000.0f;
    }
    return self;
}

- (CGSize)collectionViewContentSize
{

    NSArray *memberArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"currentGroupMembers"];
    return CGSizeMake([memberArray count]*50 , self.collectionView.frame.size.height);
}

@end
```

As a result I get a scrollable row but the dont display if the row is larger than the screen. If I increase the height on the contensize I can see that the remaining cells are added on a second line.

How can I make sure that all my cells are on a single line?

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the flow layout documentation it says:

> For a horizontally scrolling grid, this value represents the minimum spacing between successive columns.

So if you are adding a huge value horizontally and blowing the horizontal dimensions up - much larger than the content size you set. Therefore, the flow layout will try to start the next line.

Maybe it is not necessary to subclass at all. You could set the properties of the flow layout without subclassing and let the collection view take care of the content size. With the constraints of the view and the scroll direction, it should have the desired effect.

Comment: thanks. I tried to fiddle with all the values in every possible way but it didnt work :(

Comment: I just made a test project. Works exactly as I say. Check it out at [github.com/mundstein/CollectionViewTest](https://github.com/mundstein/CollectionViewTest).